# If a function's range is not equal to its co-domain, is it well-defined?

Tags: functions

I understand that the co-domain is not same as the range. For example, if the function $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ sends $x \mapsto x^2$, then its range is not the same as its co-domain. Is it a well-defined function?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's perfectly well defined. It has a domain, codomain, and every value $x$ of the domain has an associated value $f(x)=x^2$ which lies in the codomain. Just because the codomain and range are unequal doesn't mean the function is not well-defined. There wouldn't be much point in differentiating the two if it was necessary they be equal, after all.

Comment: Thank you! So is it safe to claim that a bijective function is always well-defined?

Comment: You're being told it's a function in the first place, so certainly.